# Why this behavior when declaring pointers in C++ using Unix and Windows systems?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, unix

I didn't found this question in Stack Overflow or Google, so sorry if it's a duplicate.

As I know, variables in C/C++ are not initialized. But recently a strange situation occur to me when using pointers. See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test {
    int i;
};

struct Box{
    Test *var;
};

int main() {
    Box *t = new Box;
    cout << t->var;
}
```

In Windows, the output I get is something like (what is expected):

```
0x3e0178
```

But, in Unix systems, the output is:

```
0x0
```

Why this happen? Does the compiler initialize the pointers in a recursive way when `new` is invoked in Unix systems?

Also, with common variables the same happens. For the code below, the results are `0` in Unix systems and `4385838` in Windows:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

**UPDATE**

In another test, the behavior this time was the same in both systems: the pointer `p` points to a random address in the memory.

```
int main() {
    int *p;
    cout << p;
}
```

Just to explain my question: I know we have to initialize the variables before using it, but a student was asking me why his program works fine in Unix systems and not in Windows. I found this pointer issue in his program, and I want to give a feedback.

Comment: That member was never value-initialized nor assigned. As such even *evaluating* it invokes *undefined behavior*. Likewise with `i` in the second snippet.

Comment: So, when this is evaluated, kind of a _default behavior_ is used?

Comment: No, unless a value has been *established* either by you or by the constructs of the language (ex: if `i` were a *global* or *static* in the second snippet, the standard dictates it will be zero-initialized unless you override that initialization), you cannot assume you'll get *defined* behavior when you evaluate it. Don't confuse *defined* behavior with *observed* behavior. Defined behavior is afforded by the standard, and is observable. Observed behavior is just that; observed, but that doesn't mean jack about it being *defined*.

Comment: @Who: You sure that's UB? As far as i can recall, the possibility of trap representations is implementation defined, and thus it's only ID whether the read is bad (UB), or you are guaranteed to read a valid value undisturbed, even if there are no guarantees about what it is...

Comment: @Rick: Never code for observed behavior, always follow the contract, or any change at all in your environment, even proximity to upper management, might make your software ignonimously fail. On second though, make that **especially**.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes, I agree with you. I just wanted to understand properly why this happens. So,  I also could explain it to my student. Anyway, I think your answer is the correct one for this problem. Thanks for your help. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all modern (multiuser) operating systems, memory received directly form the os is zeroed, in order to avoid information leakage. What happens, is probably the Unix systems, because far less startup code must be run to set up a proper C runtime environment, `main()` by dumb luck got virgin memory, not reusing stack space previously used for a different function, to store i. The other possible explanation is, someone just stored a 0 there before.

Anyway, don't rely on it for heavens sake.

Comment: I was thinking the same: that Unix systems, by dumb luck (as you said), fill zeros in the memory for a C program (or maybe, fill with zeros any uninitialized variables). But, if I write a new program, declaring `int *p;` and in the next line `cout << p`, the output is the same as when in Windows: a random address in the memory.

Comment: Yes: one should not rely on it. But AFAICR, linux zeroes blocks before handing them for sbrk(), so the first new's will come all-zeroed-out... :) *but don't rely on it* because the next allocations are done intra-process and they *will* come with garbage on them.

Comment: As i said, every modern OS does that. Also, i mentioned the second possible way he might _magically_ have gotten the 0.